# How to check if call to CALayer.removeAnimationForKey() is finished in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a repeating animation in my iOS app which works fine. At some point I want to 'reset' the animation. The solution I have now is the following:

```
movingView.layer.removeAnimationForKey("transform")
animateView()
```

So I remove the running animation and start a new one. The problem is that it only works if I put in a delay of say 0.05 seconds between the two calls. Without the delay I have to call the 'reset' method twice to make it work.

Of course setting the delay is not the way to go so how can I make the program to wait for the 'removeAnimationForKey' to finish before starting the next statement?

PA

Comment: Do you redo the animation manually ? You can also use repeatCount on your CAAnimation to repeat it for forever.

Comment: I make use of the .Repeat option:

`UIView.animateWithDuration(waveTime, delay: 0, options: [.CurveLinear, .Repeat ], animations: {
            self.movingView.transform =
                CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-self.view.frame.width, 0)},
            completion: {   (value: Bool) in self.movingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)})
    }`

Comment: I had the same problem at one point, and I wrote a library that allows you create an animation, and trigger another animation on near perfect precision at the end of a running animation. It uses the CADisplayLink in the background and triggers the next animation just at the right time by pre-calculating the values in the near final steps of a running animation :) https://github.com/AntonTheDev/FlightAnimator